# Energy of a charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics

Is it legitimate to calculate the energy of a continuous charge distribution, with charge distribution $\rho$ as follows:
$$E=\frac{1}{2} e^2 \int d^3 x' \int d^3 x'' \rho(x')\rho(x'') \frac{1}{|x'-x''|}?$$
I don't see why not, but if we let $\rho$ be a constant $\rho(x) = N/V$ for a system of volume $V,$ then changing variables to $x=x'-x''$ and temporarily inserting a factor of $e^{-\mu |x'-x''|}$ gives
$$E=\frac{1}{2} e^2 \left( \frac{N}{V} \right)^2 \int d^3 x' \int d^3 x \frac{e^{-\mu |x|}}{|x|} = \frac{1}{2} e^2  \frac{N^2}{V} \frac{4 \pi}{\mu^2}$$
Which diverges as we let $\mu \to 0$.

Comment: Your notation is unusual for electrostatics. Normally $\rho$ is a charge density, not a number density.

Comment: Isn't V~1/mu^2 ? If yes, then the limit actually does nothing beause it acts on a constant. AFAIK the electrostatic energy is only a problem for point charges (infinite self-energy).

Comment: Have you tried a finite distribution like a ball?

Comment: @G.Smith This is coming from Sakurai page 467. Instead of $E$ they write $H_b$ - this is the "background" term for the Hamiltonian of a degenerate electron gas.

Comment: @oliver I'm not sure what you mean by the "limit acts on a constant" ?

Comment: @Jbag1212: lim(constant)=constant. This refers to my assumption that V*mu^2=constant. But I don't know if I got this right from your question. Isn't mu something like the diameter of the integral and hence, the dimension of the charge distribution?

Comment: @oliver \mu$ would be a "screened" Coulomb potential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction of the seemingly finite volume $V$ obscures the fact that you are actually just introducing a constant charge distribution
$$\rho_0:=\frac{N}{V}=const.$$
over the whole $R^3$-space, and this has of course infinite energy because it represents infinite charge. Neither $V$ nor the Yukawa potential is of any relevance here. Instead of using a Yukawa potential and letting the Yukawa mass tend to zero, you could, after the change of variables, just integrate the Coulomb potential in spherical coordinates, which leads to
$$\int \frac{1}{r}d^3 r=4\pi\int_0^\infty r^2 \frac{1}{r}dr=4\pi\int_0^\infty rdr=\infty$$